# Rally rest API - updating task estimate fails

Tags: rally

Here is a code snippet:

```
  task["WorkProduct"] = storyref;
  task["Project"] = projectRef;
  task["Workspace"] = workspaceRef;
  task["Estimate"] = Convert.ToString  equalTaskEst);
  OperationResult result = restApi.Update(task["_ref"], task);
```

I'm bale to delete and create `tasks` with no issues. But update, does not give error nor it updates any column values

Answer (score 1):

Check the errors you are getting from the `OperationResult`:

Like so:

```
if (!OperationResult.Success)
{
    OperationResult.Errors.ToList().ToString();
}
```

With `Console.log` or whatever way you want to display them.

Getting the exact errors from Rally might shed some light on your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is the task completed?  I don't think it will allow you to update estimates or todo values if the task is already marked as done.  Also, Estimate is a numeric field so you probably do not want to submit it as a string value as your code above seems to be doing...